# python upload file by requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

when i use curl to upload data to server everything is ok but when i use requests in python, api server not accepted the request.

> Blockquote

curl:

```
curl -X POST   https://tapi.bale.ai/botXXX/Senddocument \
-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data' \
-F chat_id=2040137555 \
-F document=@/var/tmp/2706021400.pdf \
-F caption=caption
```

requests:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
}
files = {
    'chat_id': (None, '2040137555'),
    'document': ('/var/tmp/2706021400.pdf', open('/var/tmp/2706021400.pdf', 'rb')),
    'caption': (None, 'caption'),
}
response = requests.post('https://tapi.bale.ai/botXXX/Senddocument', headers=headers, files=files)
```

Comment: It might be because you've included a path for the optional file-name. Try changing `'/var/tmp/2706021400.pdf'` to just `'2706021400.pdf'`. If that solves it, then the process that is handling the upload doesn't have access to upload the file into the path `/var/tmp/`.

Comment: I change it but not work